# how to show image over blurred background

Tags: css, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
          const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);

          <Paper
            onMouseOver={() => setHover(true)}
            onMouseOut={() => setHover(false)}
            style={{
              width: '100%',
              height: 445,
              boxShadow: '0px 2px 5px ' + Colors.third + '66',
              backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
              backgroundPosition: 'center center',
              backgroundImage: hover ? `url(${preview})` : ''
            }}
            className={hover ? 'image-paper' : ''}
          >
            some test text
          </Paper>
```

and the following css:

```
.image-paper {
  filter: blur(6px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(6px);
}
```

above is the result:
[image]

and above is the goal:
[image]

Comment: what lies over a blured element will be also blured if it is a children. You need to stack two elements, the blured one, and then another one on top of it .

Answer (score 0):

the unblured element element cannot be a child of the blured element,
here a possible exemple of two stacked element with only one blured *(those 2 img can be any other tag with content)*:

```css
.Overlay {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  object-fit: scale-down;
  filter: blur(0);
}

.blur {
  filter: blur(5px) hue-rotate(160deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="Overlay">
  <img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/mars_planet/mars_planet_PNG7.png" width="640" height="480" class="blur" />
  <img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/avatar/avatar_PNG29.png" width="640 " height="480 " />
</div>
```

Comment: it is not the same use case. In my example under the image there is paper content. In your proposal there are 2 images. My aim is to blur the whole paper content and over it to show a button

Comment: @BDimitrov I told you those 2 image can be any other tag with content inside, the method remains the same , use your own containers once you understood why both cannot be Parent/child but can be sibbling piled on top of each others ;) Happy coding